# Number of subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $\mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a countably infinite dimensional vector space.
>
> Is the number of subspaces with countably infinite dimension countable?

Comment: Do we know something about the field $\Bbb{F}$? $\Bbb{R}^2$ already has uncountably many subspaces.

Comment: Suppose that $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{F}_{p}$ for some $p$ a prime number.

Comment: So the space looks like the polynomial ring $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$? I think the space of all functions $\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{F}$ has uncountable dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a countably infinite basis for some vector space, then its powerset is uncountable. Distinct subsets of $\mathcal{B}$ span distinct subspaces, so there are uncountably many of them.

Observe that only countably many subsets of $\mathcal{B}$ are finite, so the power set contains uncountably many infinite subsets (all necessarily countable).